# Find pairs of integers from an array having difference of k (using hash tables only)

Tags: algorithm, sorting, hashtable

Given an array of distinct integer values, count the number of pairs of integers that have difference k. For example, given the array {1, 7, 5, 9, 2, 12, 3} and the difference k = 2.

Need solution using hash tables only.

Comment: Check out Method 4 in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-pairs-difference-equal-k/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put all the numbers into a hash table. Then, for each of the original numbers `n` check if `n+k` is in the hash table. Count, how many hits you have found.

Comment: if you can provide the algorithm for that.

Comment: I thought, I just did that. What are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in O(N) time implemented in Javascript:

```
function countSets(values, k) {
  let map1 = new Map();

  values.forEach((value) => {
    map1.set(value);
  });

  let count = 0;
  values.forEach((value) => {
    if(map1.has(value + k))count++;
  });
  
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## 100% Correct python solution

### Approach

1. Count the **frequencies** of each **number** in **nums**
2. Counter returns a **dictionary** of **frequencies** for each number found in **nums**
3. Loop & sum the matches of all possible pairs that are in the **freq**
4. Print the counter **c**

### Complexity

Time complexity:
**O(n)**

Space complexity:
**O(n)**

```
from collections import Counter

nums = [1, 7, 5, 9, 2, 12, 3]
k = 2

freq = Counter(nums)

c = 0      
[c := c + freq[num + k] for num in nums]

print(c)
```